# SQL Server Express - Detach/Reattach Data loss possible?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to lose data during the detach/reattach process?

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong this weekend..
I was moving user databases from one physical HD to another.
I was using the SA account, detach database, copy both .mdf and .ldf to new location, then reattach database with path pointing to new location.

During this process detach/reattach the MSSMS console faulted saying default database no longer available (or something similar).

I reconnected with a different account and resumed the moving process - I didn't know how to change the default db at the time in MSSMS.

I verified that all the databases were listed, and double checked the file size of the original and new location and they were the same.  Here I should have looked at the actual data, but didn't.

Later I came to find out that some of the most recent data (last 4 months) was gone from one database - I'm assuming it was the database when the console faulted.

Comment: On its own, no. If you detach a database, then any transactions will be rolled back, or allowed to complete (depending on your actions). This could be seen as data loss. Also, while detached, any attempts to make changes to the database would fail. As for it meaning that data that already existed on the database being lost no. Of course, if you did something "foolish" like have your backup strategy set to FULL, but hadn't done any backups for 4 months, detached, deleted the log file and then attached...

Comment: Thanks for the response - our back ups are performed daily, so it wasn't a back up issue.  I just re-ran though the process above with the 2 databases that had issue and they appear to have all the proper information now.  Only other thing I can think of is possibly file permission issues - although I don't see that really being the case.  This time i used the SA account.

Comment: You really should be using backup and restore to move databases around.